# API Design for Timeouts: TimeoutException or boolean return with out parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, api, timeout

The scenario is RPC over message queues - since the underlying mechanism is asynchronous, clients should specify how long they want to wait for a response before timing out.  As the client, which of these two code snippets would you rather use?

Most importantly: as a user of the GetResponseTo() method, **why** would you prefer one over the other?  How does your choice make **your code** more extensible, more readable, more testable, etc?

```
try
{
    IEvent response = _eventMgr.GetResponseTo(myRequest, myTimeSpan);
    // I have my response!
}
catch(TimeoutException te)
{
    // I didn't get a response to 'myRequest' within 'myTimeSpan'
}
```

OR

```
IEvent myResponse = null;

if (_eventMgr.GetResponseTo(myRequest, myTimeSpan, out myResponse)
{
    // I got a response!
}
else
{
    // I didn't get a response... :(
}
```

For your information, here's the current implementation of GetResponseTo():

```
public IEvent GetResponseTo(IEvent request, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    if (null == request) { throw new ArgumentNullException("request"); }

    // create an interceptor for the request
    IEventInterceptor interceptor = new EventInterceptor(request, timeout);

    // tell the dispatcher to watch for a response to this request
    _eventDispatcher.AddInterceptor(interceptor);

    // send the request
    _queueManager.SendRequest(request);

    // block this thread while we wait for a response.  If the timeout elapses,
    // this will throw a TimeoutException
    interceptor.WaitForResponse();

    // return the intercepted response
    return interceptor.Response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have elected to use the out parameter.

I wanted to mark someone else as the answer, but I am not able to do so.  I attempted to implement the TPL-based approach, but was unable to do so, based on the question/answer that I linked in my comments.

I do not want to muddy my event model by introducing even more concepts, as @sll suggests.

And even though @dasheddot prefers the exception Version, @sll has a good point that someone trying to send a bunch of requests and get a bunch of responses in a loop might have to deal with a lot of exceptions.

```
// potentially 10 exceptions?  meh... let's not go down this road.
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  try
  {
     IEvent response = _eventMgr.GetResponseTo(myRequest, myTimeSpan);

     // I have my response!
  }
  catch(TimeoutException te)
  {
     // I didn't get a response to 'myRequest' within 'myTimeSpan'
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither first nor second, I would like to use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), which is the recommended way of doing all things asynchronous beginning with .NET 4.5:

```
Task<IEvent> task = _eventMgr.GetResponseToAsync(myRequest);

if (task.Wait(myTimeSpan))
{
    // I got a response!
}
else
{
    // I didn't get a response... :(
}
```

Comment: Since method call really is synchronous it does not make sense to use TPL, @dtb: what are you think?

Comment: The underlying mechanism is asynchronous; I see no value in trying to hide this fact behind an abstraction that leaks as soon as a timeout, network error, etc. occurs. However, it depends a bit on the message queue library if it makes sense to use TPL or not.

Comment: AFAIK some enterprise messaging libraries provides both Async and Sync methods API so caller could consider which one to use in each particular case, so both sync and async methods makes sense

Comment: why would the message queue library make a difference?  It's the .NET client for RabbitMQ.

Comment: You need to map the operations of the library to TPL constructs. If that's not possible or too difficult, then TPL is obviously not a good fit. I'm not familiar with the .NET client for RabbitMQ.

Comment: I'm writing something very similar to spring-amqp for .net (yes, I know spring has a .net implementation - I have reasons), so I have control over the API.

Comment: If you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315866/how-can-code-within-a-task-know-that-it-has-timed-out
you'll see that I have an issue with using TPL for this.  When _eventDispatcher is told to dispatch the response that interceptor is waiting for, _eventDispatcher will not know whether the Task has timed out.  Neither will interceptor, since it is created in the task itself.  So, responses will be dispatched to their recipients after the client's Task<IEvent> timed out.

Answer (score 1):

You could look to use AutoResetEvent class this will handle the plumbing for second one.

Try to avoid your first code snippet as exceptions are expensive

Comment: Exceptions are expensive if you loop lot of times through Methods which through exceptions in the usual Case. If it is Not the usual Case exception should Be used

Comment: Yes, the implementation of EventInterceptor.WaitForResponse() is actually waiting on an AutoResetEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are heavy and messy, each API method call should be wrapped by try/catch/finally to hanle custom exception. This approach is not developer-friendly so I do not like it.

Considering that `GetResponse()` call itself is synchronous for API consumer - it is pretty normal to return a value of operation, but I would suggest introducing something more abstract and informative rather than simple bool state, so you can return any state provided by the underlying messaging system, this could be a custom error code, message, or even object. So since this is API - put interface as well:

```
enum OperationStatus
{
   Unknown,
   Timeout,
   Ok
}

// pretty simple, only message and status code
interface IOperationResult<T>
{
      OperationStatus Status { get; }
      string Message { get; }
      T Item { get; }      
}


class GetResponseResult : IOperationResult<IEvent>
{
   ...
} 

class EventManager
{
     public IOperationResult<IEvent> GetResponseTo(
                                      IRequest request, 
                                      TimeSpan timeInterval)
    {    
        GetResponseResult result;  

        // wait for async request                 
        // ...

        if (timeout)
        {
          result = new GetResponseResult 
                        { 
                           Status = OperationStatus.Timeout,
                           Message = underlyingMessagingLib.ErrorMessage
                        };
        }
        else
        {
          result = new GetResponseResult 
                        { 
                           Status = OperationStatus.Ok,
                           Item = response
                        };
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: the implementation of the GetResponseTo() method blocks your thread - making it appear as though it sent the request and got a response synchronously -- even though it all happened over asynch pub/sub.

Comment: In addition, if I exposed an event like you suggest, it would be up to you to determine which request timed out (maybe you have many outstanding requests).

Comment: @John Ruiz: EventArgs could provide you an information regarding timeouted request, buf tor syncronous API neither this nor TPL does not make sense

Comment: Thanks for offering code!  This would work and I won't call it wrong, but what I don't like about it is that I've made my API more complex by introducing IOperationResult<T> and OperationStatus.  By using TPL, all my clients need to learn is IEventManager and IEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would prefer the exception Version. If i specify some timeout my opinion is that this IS a exception then if i couldn't get a result within the specified timespan. I don't think event based notification is the best decision here. The following Logic depends on the result so it doesn't make Sense for me. 
But if you want to provide asynchronous Methods too, the Task thing is a good idea like stated by dtb